# Selection of primitives when clicked by mouse not working

Tags: c, opengl

I'm developing a solitary board game, which has a piece per square, and each piece can be of two colors. If I click a piece, the four adjacent ones (top, bottom, left and right) all change to the next color.

I'm having problems with detecting in which piece the mouse was clicked on.

I have the following code for the mouse callback:

```
GLuint selectBuf[BUFSIZE]; // BUFSIZE is defined to be 512
GLint hits;
GLint viewport[4];

if( ( state != GLUT_DOWN ) && ( button != GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON ) )
    return;

glGetIntegerv (GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
glSelectBuffer (BUFSIZE, selectBuf);
(void) glRenderMode (GL_SELECT);
glInitNames();
glPushName(0);
gluPickMatrix ((GLdouble) x, (GLdouble) y, 20.0,20.0, viewport);

draw(GL_SELECT); // the function that does the rendering of the pieces

hits = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);

processHits (hits, selectBuf); // a function that displays the hits obtained
```

Now, the problem I have is that I don't quite know how to process the hits occurred which are on selectBuf. I have the following code for processHits:

```
void processHits (GLint hits, GLuint buffer[])
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    GLuint ii, jj, names, *ptr;

    printf ("hits = %d\n", hits);
    ptr = (GLuint *) buffer;
    for(i = 0; i < hits; i++) {
        printf("hit n. %d ---> %d",i, *(buffer+i));
    }
}
```

Finally, in the `draw` function I have:

```
void draw(GLenum mode) {
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLuint x,y;

    int corPeca; //colourpiece in english
    int corCasa; //colourHouse (each square has a diferent color, like checkers)
    for (x =0; x < colunas; x++) { //columns
        for(y=0; y < colunas; y++) {
            if ( (tabuleiro[y*colunas+x].peca) == 1) //board
                corPeca = 1;
            else
                corPeca = 2;

            if((tabuleiro[y*colunas+x].quadrado)==1) //square
                corCasa = 1;
            else
                corCasa = 2;

            if (mode == GL_SELECT){
                GLuint name = 4;
                glLoadName(name);
            }
            desenhaCasa(x,y,corCasa);       //draws square
            desenhaPeca(x,y,corPeca, mode); //draws piece
        }
    }
}
```

Now, has you can see, I've just put 4 into the buffer with `glLoadName`. However when I pull the number out in `processHits` I always get 1. I know that's because of the structure of the buffer that gets the hits, but what is that structure and how can I access the number 4?

Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of the selection buffer is a bit more complex than that. For each hit, a "hit record" consisting of several values is appended to the selection buffer. You can look at [Question 20.020](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm) in the OpenGL FAQ for details. In your case, where there is only one name on the stack at a time, the hit record will consist 4 values, with the name being the fourth one. So, in your `processHits` function, you should write

```
for(i = 0; i < hits; i++) {
    printf("hit n. %d ---> %d",i, *(buffer+4*i+3));
}
```

Also, the size of your name buffer should probably be 4 times longer as well.